# Given a Banach Algebra $A$ and elements $x,y \in A$. If $x$ and $xy$ are invertible, then so is $y$.

Tags: banach-algebras

A silly question, but I don't see the answer.
This question is from Rudin's Functional Analysis, Chapter 10, Exercise 1a).

It's obvious that $y$ has a left inverse as $((xy)^{-1}x)y=e$, where $e$ is the unit of the algebra. However, starting with $y((xy)^{-1}x)$, I cannot proceed further. Does this suggest that  I need to 'venture beyond' the multiplicative group structure, maybe introduce ideas from the ring structure on the Banach Algebra? ( I'm thinking of something analogous to the proof where $e-xy$ is invertible if and only if $e-yx$ is invertible. There, if $z$ is the inverse of $e-xy$, then, $e+yzx$ is the inverse of $e-yx$.)

Comment: Hint: a product of two invertible elements is certainly invertible.  Given the information you have, can you write y as the product of two invertible elements?

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing you meant Exercise 2(a)?

Let $p = y((xy)^{-1}x)$, then $xp = xy((xy)^{-1}x) = x$, since $x$ is invertible, it follows that $p=e$.

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of $x^{-1}xy$ is $(xy)^{-1}x$, since $x^{-1}xy\cdot (xy)^{-1}x=e$ and 
$(xy)^{-1}xx^{-1}xy=e$. Hence $y$ is invertible.